# Hidden Segments Not working when added via web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to secure my MVC application, and I want to hide the standard folder structure from url sniffers.

For example. I have a Controllers folder. If I attempt to reach it via

> http://www.myDomain.com/Controllers

I am getting a 403.14 status code. if I do a directory that doesn't exist:

> http://www.myDomain.com/NonExistantDirectory

I get a 404.

I would like to hide these standard mvc directories, so that you can't do directory sniffing. **So here is my question:** I can add hidden secgments via IIS, and then I get the 404 response I wanted, BUT when I add the following xml to my web config, I still get the 403.14 status code.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="Controllers"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
...
```

Any reason this way of adding hidden segments doesn't work, but the manual manipulation does?
(note: i am running window 8, with IIS 8)

Comment: When you publish to a web server, those MVC directories do not exist on the web server.  All the code in the controller directory is compiled into the bin/{project}.dll.  The only reason that directory would show up is because you have a file in there set to "Content".

Comment: Thanks Tommy, I forgot that while i run with IIS pointing to my dev folder, code that is deployed does not include these folders, so I will not get the 403. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running your application in IIS Integrated IIS pipeline mode which uses the `<system.webServer>` section instead of `<system.web>`. For example if you are running this in Visual Studio ensure that you have hosted your application in IIS Express instead of the built-in Cassini web server. If on the other hand you are hosting your application in a real IIS web server ensure that the application pool is using Integrated Pipeline mode in contrast to Classic Pipeline mode.

Comment: I have verified, I am using Integrated mode for my AppPool, still same result :(. I am running the project in "use local iis web server" mode as well.

Comment: I even restarted IIS, and I am still seeing this issue.